# How to control jenkins slave node in command line?

Tags: jenkins

I use docker container as jenkins slave, and need to restart the container when the images are updated. Therefore I need to know the [Jenkins remote API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) to control it.

Where can I find the complete control command in JSON request ?

Groovy script is not considered since the command line will be embedded into the script.

Some hints in answer [Reconfigure and reboot a Hudson/Jenkins slave as part of a build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543413/reconfigure-and-reboot-a-hudson-jenkins-slave-as-part-of-a-build) , but it is not complete

```
curl -d "offlineMessage=&json=%7B%22offlineMessage%22%3A+%22%22%7D&Submit=Yes" http://JENKINS_HOST/computer/THE_NODE_TO_DISCONNECT/doDisconnect
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not answering the question but if you want to connect a node you can use:

```
curl -d "Submit=Yes" http://JENKINS/computer/NODE_NAME/launchSlaveAgent
```